# Single sign on in Teams application between tabs and the bot

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

Using the Bot Framework w/ Microsoft.Bot.Builder v4.6.3

Is it possible to have users sign in only once using the [web-based authentication flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso), doesn't matter if they sign in via tabs or via bot conversation? If they sign in via a link from a tab, I'd like to have the bot know about this.

I have tried the following for test, omitting any security checks:

1. All pages are with the following js files imported:

   - https://statics.teams.microsoft.com/sdk/v1.4.2/js/MicrosoftTeams.min.js
   - https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/oidc-client/1.9.1/oidc-client.min.js
2. On load, the tab page executes `microsoftTeams.initialize();`
3. Add a button to the tab page:

```
<button onclick="authenticate()">Authenticate</button>
```

4. The `authenticate` function contains the following:

```
function authenticate() {
    microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate({
        url: window.location.origin + "/tabs/tabAuthStart",
        width: 600,
        height: 535,
        successCallback: function (result) {
            // The debug function just displays what's sent to it using document.write()
            debug(result);
        },
        failureCallback: function (reason) {
            debug(reason);
        }
    });
}
```

5. The `tabAuthStart` page contains the following script which is executed on page load:

```
microsoftTeams.initialize();

const mgr = new Oidc.UserManager({
    userStore: new Oidc.WebStorageStateStore(),
    authority: '<my-identity-server>',
    client_id: '<my-id-srv-client>',
    redirect_uri: window.location.origin + '/tabs/tabAuthCallback',
    response_type: 'id_token token',
    scope: '<my-requested-scopes>',
    accessTokenExpiringNotificationTime: 10,
    automaticSilentRenew: true,
    filterProtocolClaims: true,
    loadUserInfo: true
});

mgr.signinRedirect();
```

6. After a successful sign in at the identity provider, I'm redirected back to `/tabs/tabAuthCallback`
7. On load, the `/tabs/tabAuthCallback` executes the following code:

```
microsoftTeams.initialize();

var mgr = new Oidc.UserManager({ userStore: new Oidc.WebStorageStateStore(), loadUserInfo: true, filterProtocolClaims: true });

mgr.signinRedirectCallback().then(function (user) {
    // I expected something involving a bot to happen after calling this
    microsoftTeams.authentication.notifySuccess({
        idToken: user.id_token,
        accessToken: user.access_token,
        tokenType: user.token_type,
        expiresIn: user.expires_at
    })
}).catch(function (err) {
    microsoftTeams.authentication.notifyFailure("UnexpectedFailure: " + err);
});
```

8. The pop-up window is closed and the `successCallback` function from the tab is executed successfully with the user information that I have sent. However, the bot is not in any way notified about this (as far as I know). I have set a breakpoint in the bot controller action resolved by `POST /api/messages` but it's never hit.

Do I need to handle this manually? I.e. pass the user info to the back-end? But even if so, how do I know which Teams user to associate this user info (i.e. access token) to?

If this is possible to do in a reliable and secure way, would it also be possible in the opposite direction, i.e. having the user token available to the tab if they have already been authenticated from a bot conversation or a messaging extension? Is there a reliable way to identify a Teams user who's navigating tabs, in order to obtain their access token from the back-end, assuming the back-end already obtained them via the authentication mechanism?

Comment: Are you still working on this? What you need is [Single Sign-On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso)(SSO) which means if a user consents to use your app on desktop, they won’t have to consent again on mobile and will be automatically logged in, but this is supported only in developer preview

Comment: @ranusharao thanks for the comment. I am aware of that SSO solution, but it only works with AAD authentication, whereas I need to make this happen using a custom identity server. The documentation is vague regarding this matter, somewhere it implies it can't be done, somewhere it implies it can.

Comment: Yup its vague as it is still in Developer Preview and the documentation does not specify anything in detail about the same and it is not related to botframework. I would suggest you to file your issue on the [SSO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso) page feedback and someone from Teams docs team might be able to help you walk through this type of scenario.

Comment: Any luck on this?  We use IdentityServer as our identity provider, and would love to know of better ways to get Teams to work with it instead of AAD.

Comment: @DaleyKD unfortunately no, it *is* possible to make Teams work with IdentityServer by using oidc-client-js and it's possible to reuse the same authentication mechanism when using the bot, but I am not aware of the solution to make the bot and the tab share the authentication info.